# Get value from JSON using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

I am trying to export json as a variable:

`$ export VARIABLE='[{"id": 2, "name": "job", "description": "job", "token": "toknetokentokentoken/token="}]'`

`$ echo $VARIABLE | jq .`

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "job",
    "description": "job",
    "token": "toknetokentokentoken/token="
  }
]
```

and then I am trying to get the value from token:

`TOKEN=$(echo "$VARIABLE" | jq -r '.[] | select (.name == "job").token')`

but it returns nothing. I am looking on to that but I can't find the problem.

Comment: The expression with $() behaves as expected using bash going back at least to 3.2.  I suspect there's a mismatch between the Q as posed and the circumstances associated with the anomalous behavior.

Comment: When you say "returns nothing", do you mean the value of `TOKEN` is the empty string, or that the assignment produces no output. Assignments *don't* produce output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
VARIABLE='[{"id": 2, "name": "job", "description": "job", "token": "toknetokentokentoken/token="}]'
TOKEN=$(echo "$VARIABLE"|jq '.[] | select(.name == "job").token')
echo "$TOKEN"
```

**Edit:** as suggested a few clarifications:

the OP did not clariy on the *it erturns nothing part* but as @chepner pointed out in the comments: assingments don't procude output

backticks and `$()` are interchangeable, you should use `$()` since backticks are obsolete and don't support nesting

Comment: I updated my answer with the exact commands used in my local (bash) terminal

Comment: Why are you introducing backticks at all? They're obsolete.

Comment: ...if you use backticks, there's a bunch of extra escaping needed (when nesting them or, in some cases, using backslashes within them) that isn't called for with `$( )`. As such, they're *not* in fact interchangeable.

Comment: Also, `echo "$FOO" | bar` is typically slower than `bar <<<"$FOO"`, at least on systems modern enough to have `TMPDIR` be on in-memory storage.

Comment: @user1859022, could you [edit] this answer to be more explicit about what mistake the OP was making, and generally what you had to change? Without more explanation it's hard for someone else to learn from reading this answer, and, well, that's what they're for. :)